# Mandar datos de un beginform a controller de 3 dropdown distintos

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, formularios

Hola Desarrolladores tengo una duda de conocimiento resulta que realice tres dropdown que me solicitaron y la cosa es que tengo que hacer que envíe la informacion mediante un boton al controlador en MVC 2

acá el codigo aspx

```
<div class="row">

            <h2 style="font-size: 20px;">Seleccione Origen de Carga de Datos</h2>
           <%using (Html.BeginForm("OrigenDatos", "Origen", FormMethod.Post))
               {%>
            <div class="col-lg-12 col-sm-12" style="margin-top: 15px;">           

                <div class="col-lg-4 col-xs-12" style="margin-top: 5px;">
                    <label for="DropDownList2">Seleccione Origen 1</label>
                    <div class="col-xs-12">
                        <select name="ctl00$MainContent$DropDownList1" id="MainContent_DropDownList1" class="salutation " style="height: 17px; width: 202px; display: none;">
                            <option value="1">SIGO</option>
                            <option value="2">MEDIDORES PROPIOS</option>
                            <option value="3">COORDINADOR</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-4 col-xs-12" style="margin-top: 5px;">
                    <label for="DropDownList2">Seleccione Origen 2</label>
                    <div class="col-xs-12">
                        <select name="ctl00$MainContent$DropDownList2" id="MainContent_DropDownList2" class="salutation " style="height: 17px; width: 202px; display: none;">
                            <option value="1">SIGO</option>
                            <option value="2">MEDIDORES PROPIOS</option>
                            <option value="3">COORDINADOR</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-4 col-xs-12" style="margin-top: 5px;">
                    <label for="DropDownList2">Seleccione Origen 3</label>
                    <div class="col-xs-12">
                        <select name="ctl00$MainContent$DropDownList3" id="MainContent_DropDownList3" class="salutation " style="height: 17px; width: 202px; display: none;">
                            <option value="1">SIGO</option>
                            <option value="2">MEDIDORES PROPIOS</option>
                            <option value="3">COORDINADOR</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>                  
                 <input type="submit" value="Enviar" class="btn btn-primary" style="margin-top: 1px;">
                   <%} %>
               </div>
               </form>                
        </div>            
    </div>
```

Nosé como recibir esta info y guardarla en objetos distintos (Conforme a su origen = origen 1, origen 2, origen 3)

estoy tratando de hacerlo así pero no me ingresa al controlador

```
public class OrigenController : Controller
{
    // GET: Origen
    public ActionResult Origen()
    {
        return View("~/Views/Origen/Origen.aspx");
    }
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult OrigenDatos(string MainContent_DropDownList1, string MainContent_DropDownList2, string MainContent_DropDownList3)
    {
        var origen1 = MainContent_DropDownList1;
        var origen2 = MainContent_DropDownList2;
        var origen3 = MainContent_DropDownList3;

        return View("~/Views/Origen/Origen.aspx");
    }
}
```

Qué estoy haciendo mal?

Se agradece respuesta.

Comment: Hola ¿has probado a poner un punto de interrupción en el método del controlador e inspeccionar el contenido de Request.Form? Igual es algo tan simple como que en el cuerpo del post no se llaman MainContent_DropDownListx sino Ctl00_MainContent_DropDownListx (porque en realidad los post se hacen en base a name y no a id y no se cómo gestionan las vistas aspx el name porque siempre ha usado Razor con MVC)?

Comment: Estoy usando MVC 2 con aspx cambie el name del id de los dropdownlist y los name los recibo como string en mi accionresult hice el debug pero no ingresa al controller ese es el problema. y he enviado otros formularios y si los envia nose porque en este caso no lo hace.

Comment: ¿El panel de red del navegador de las F12 qué información te da sobre el Post? ¿Te da algún tipo de error? De paso puedes comprobar el nombre de los parámetros serializados y la url a la que está intentando mandarlo.